# Ireland - Temporary consulting work needs visa?

Tags: working-visas, ireland, canadian-citizens

Would I legally be able to do consulting work on location in Ireland during a short stay (visa-free under 3 months), billed to my home country as a foreign service provider (rather than being paid a salary)?

Or does that require a working visa?

Home country & citizenship: Canadian.

Comment: It probably depends on the nature of the work.

Comment: What do you mean? It's IT work. Which could in theory be done remotely, but would be much better in-person than teleconferencing constantly as we kickoff a project phase.

Comment: I mean is it work such as the installation or configuration of a product (okay as a business visitor under US rules, at least) or is it more like the development of new software (requires work permission).

Comment: Sorry I kinda forgot about this.

Even after consulting the Irish government, we weren't able to have a clear answer as this seemed to be walking a thin line.

We opted for doing a short stay there where I _received_ training, was introduced to the company's products and policies, etc... then went back to Canada to wait for a visa to then go back to Ireland and work on premises.

This seemed to be the best unambiguously legal way if more of a logistical challenge.

Comment: perhaps you should add that solution and any relevant findings as an answer, especially since there are no other answers posted yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you would be getting paid. If you would be getting paid in Canada by a Canada company into a Canada bank account, then your status is a business trip and you don't need a work permit. Otherwise you do need it.

Explanation comes from Irish Revenue because Revenue makes difference between business trip into Ireland and work in Ireland.

https://www2.deloitte.com/ie/en/pages/tax/articles/changes-to-the-taxation-of-business-travellers-into-Ireland.html#

> However the new guidance issued by Revenue impacts travellers coming
>   to Ireland where that individual spends greater than 30 days in
>   Ireland in a calendar year and is
>
> - Working for an Irish employer where the duties performed by the    individual are an integral part of the business activities of the
>     Irish employer, or
> - Replacing a member of staff of an Irish employer, or
> - Gaining experience working for an Irish employer, or
> - Supplied and paid by an agency (or other entity) outside the State to work for an Irish employer.
>
> Where any of those conditions are met, there will now be an obligation
>   to withhold PAYE taxes from the individual, once he or she is here for
>   more than 30 days. Up to this, such a person had to be in Ireland for
>   more than 183 days before this happened.

Comment: This sounds like a good answer, but it would definitely be one if you could [edit it](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/posts/17251/edit) to add some official or authoritative sources to support it.